# Cannot read property 'file' of null in upload

Tags: node.js, file, express, upload

I'm a beginner trying to learn Nodejs and I'm trying upload a file using express.

This is my js file : `Express5.js`

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var data='';

var multer  = require('multer');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'tmp')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended :false}));

app.use(multer({ dest : '/tmp/' }).single('file1')); 


app.get('/express_upload.html',function(req,res){
 req.sendFile(__dirname+"/"+"express_upload.html");
});

app.post('/form_upload',function(req,res){
  console.log("Name : "+req.file.name);
  console.log("Path"+req.file.path);
  console.log("Type"+req.file.type);
  var myfile = __dirname+"/"+req.file.name;

  fs.readFile(req.file.path,function(req,resp){
     fs.writeFile(myfile,data,function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            response = {
                msg : "File uploaded successfully!",
                filename : req.file.name
            };
        }

        console.log(response);      
        res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
      });
  });
});

var server=app.listen(8081,function(){
     var host = server.address().address;
     var port = server.address().port;
     console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

  });
```

This is my html form : `express_upload.html`

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<style>
    h2, h3{
        color:Crimson;
        text-align:center;}
</style>
<body bgcolor="MistyRose">
    <h2 >Welcome</h2>
    <hr>
    <h3>Node.js </h3>
    <form action="http://127.0.0.1:8081/form_upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file1" size=50>
        <br>

        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="UploadFile">
    </form>
</body>
```

Whenever i try to upload a file it gives error Cannot read property 'file' of null.

Error :

```
C:\Users\nikita\Documents\NodeJspractice>node express5.js
Example app listening at http://:::8081
Name : undefined
Path\tmp\de5a6a92ec86094615cd1690e2821248
Typeundefined
C:\Users\nikita\Documents\NodeJspractice\express5.js:33
                                    filename : req.file.name
                                                   ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of null
at C:\Users\nikita\Documents\NodeJspractice\express5.js:33:21
at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:135:15)
```

I have tried most of the solutions that I was able to understand still I'm unable to resolve this. Please help if you can find any error or can propose a solution. 
Thank you

Comment: I haven't run your code but I would expect it to be associated with file1 not file. Did you inspect req?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var data='';

var multer  = require('multer');
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'tmp')));

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended :false}));

app.use(multer({ dest : '/tmp/' }).single('file1')); 


app.get('/express_upload.html',function(req,res){
req.sendFile(__dirname+"/"+"express_upload.html");
});

app.post('/form_upload',function(req,res){
console.log("Name : "+req.file.name);
console.log("Path"+req.file.path);
console.log("Type"+req.file.type);
var myfile = __dirname+"/"+req.file.name;

fs.readFile(req.file.path,function(e,file){
    fs.writeFile(myfile,data,function(err){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }else{
            response = {
                msg : "File uploaded successfully!",
                filename : req.file.originalname
            };
        }

        console.log(response);      
        res.end(JSON.stringify(response));
    });
});
});

var server=app.listen(8081,function(){
    var host = server.address().address;
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("Example app listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)
});
```

The error was because rewriting `req` in line `24`, I just change it and correct it in line `33` too.

Comment: It worked.. Thanks!! But there's something i am not able to understand.

Comment: Which part? @nikitaaggarwal

Comment: Why is filename coming as undefined in result.. Shouldn't it display the name of file??

Comment: I just update the answer, change `file.name` to `req.file.originalname`. Now It's show the filename. @nikitaaggarwal

Answer (score 1):

You overwritted the `req` object in line 26.

The convention in Nodejs callbacks is alwayes to return an `Error` object as the first parameter if an error occur, or, pass a `null` as the first parameter if no error has occur.

In youe case- there was no errors- so the `req` paremter in line 26 gets `null`. and null- doesn't have a `file` property.

---

### By the way- you have some more problems in your code.

In line 17:
`res.sendFile` instead of `req.sendFile`.

In line 21 :
`req.file.originalname` instead of `req.file.name`.

Ind in line 23 :
`req.file.mimetype` instead of `req.file.type`.

Use VSCode (or any ather IDE) to help you debug the code. put a breakpoint at any step and observe what your variables contains.